# Command line &> redirection not working?

Tags: bash

I've been using a Ruby script to help automate my testing. As a part of this script I am redirecting output from a program into a file like this:

```
`./program_name #{params} > #{temp_file}`
```

This works fine, how I'd like to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to the file. Which I would do like this:

```
`./program_name #{params} &> #{temp_file}`
```

Having added the `&`, the temp file no longer receives any output.

Note that the `&>` operator works as expected when used on the command line, it seems only to be in the Ruby script that it causes the problem.

Any ideas why this might be, and how I might get around the issue?

Comment: Are you using `/bin/sh` in the shebang? Use `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Try saying `./program_name #{params} > #{temp_file} 2>&1` instead.

Comment: `&>` may or may not work depending on your shell or even bash version.

Comment: echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: I'll give these alternate formats a go now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby. The command is opened in a sub-shell so interpretation of `&>` is by the shell/OS entirely.

Comment: I removed the ruby tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&>` is a [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Redirections). Simply use POSIX redirections:

```
`./program_name #{params} >#{temp_file} 2>&1`
```

Comment: You're going to need to reverse those redirects: `... >#{temp_file} 2>&1` -- redirect stdout first, then redirect stderr to the file stdout is pointing to.

Comment: Kindof skirts the issue which is most likely that OP was running a non [tag:bash] shell script.

Comment: @BroSlow It doesn't matter which language `program_name` is, because the redirection is happening in the [Ruby shell command context](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60). Unfortunately the documentation is mum on which shell it uses.

Comment: @l0b0 I'm not sure what you mean by "Ruby shell command context", but unless you escape it, redirection is always processed by the shell and `ruby`/`program_name` has no access to it.